# Node.js callbacks hell

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning node.js right now and I'm having troubles calling back.

I looked at Event Emitter but it doesn't seems to be relevant for me.

This is what I'm calling:

```
exports.search = function(lat, lng, Arr, callback) {

    //something

    geocoder.reverse({
        lat: lat,
        lon: lng
    }, function(err, res, callback) {

        //finding the area
        if (area !== "null") {
            pool.getConnection(function(err, connection, callback) {
                if (err) {

                } else {
                    connection.query("SOME SQL CODE", function(err, rows, fields, callback) {
                        if (found what Im looking
                            for) {
                            connection.query("SOME SQL CODE", function(err, rows, fields, callback) { //looking for something else
                                if (err) {
                                    callback(true);
                                } else {
                                    if (rows[0] === undefined) {
                                        callback(true);
                                    } else {
                                        console.log("found!");
                                        callback(null, rows[0]);
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        } else if (err) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {

        }
    });
};
```

I'm getting my "found!" in the console log, but the callback doesn't working for some reason.

If I put a callback at the end of the function " search " it does call back, do I know I'm not having a problem with the function who gets the callback.

Thank you!

Comment: You're clobbering your `callback` variable at every level there.

Comment: Also, `area` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: ...and will `area` ever actually be equal to the string `"null"`?

Comment: If you want to alleviate the deep nesting here, then I'd suggest you learn how to use promises with your async operations.  Also, please the title of your question should be a more specific summayr of the problem you are having.

Comment: Agreeing with @jfriend00 - as it is, there is a fundamental structure flaw in what you're writing. Best go back and start and the beginning and learn about the callback syntax and/or promises.

Comment: ideally you want your code to become: `getConnection.then(firstQuery).then(secondQuery).then(handleResult).catch(handleError)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the callback(null, rows[0]) is call back of function geocoder.reverse. You can change name callback of search function is callback1 and then call as below.

```
exports.search = function(lat, lng, Arr, callback1) {

//something

geocoder.reverse({
    lat: lat,
    lon: lng
}, function(err, res, callback) {

    //finding the area
    if (area !== "null") {
        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection, callback) {
            if (err) {

            } else {
                connection.query("SOME SQL CODE", function(err, rows, fields, callback) {
                    if (found what Im looking
                        for) {
                        connection.query("SOME SQL CODE", function(err, rows, fields, callback) { //looking for something else
                            if (err) {
                                callback(true);
                            } else {
                                if (rows[0] === undefined) {
                                    callback(true);
                                } else {
                                    console.log("found!");
                                    callback1(null, rows[0]);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    } else if (err) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } else {

    }
});
```

};

You can apply [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) lib to your code so that your code is clear too.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a library that helps you: like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)